# change color of squarespace calendar event based on event title

Tags: colors, calendar, squarespace

I am creating a caledar of events in Squarespace. I already know how to change the colors of the dates that have an event on them. However, I'd like to change the dates where the specific title of the event is set to "Available" to a different color. Can I do this with custom CSS?

I found some instructions on Stack overflow about changing the color of the square based on it's block id, but I couldn't make that work. I used the right click "Inspect" menu item to identify the block id, but I couldn't make the code work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Replace 'your-element-class' with the actual class or ID */
.your-element-class {
    color: #FF0000; /* Change to your desired color */
}
```